# adding custom headers using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script that i can use to add custom http headers in IIS instead of manually adding them. I did not have any luck finding anything on the web so far. Can someone please point me to right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Like [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/add) (the code part on the bottom)?

Comment: Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST `
-Name . -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders `
-AtElement @{name = "X-Frames-Options" ; value='sameorigin'}

Comment: it adds only one but when i try to add multiple at the same time it does not work.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to successfully add 2 or more headers using the following:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST `
    -Name . -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders `
    -AtElement @{name = "X-Frames-Options" ; value = 'sameorigin' }

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST `
    -Name . -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders `
    -AtElement @{name = "Cache-Control" ; value = 'private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0'}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, avoiding the cmdlets and going direct to appcmd still works:

```
PS> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webserver/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='myCustomName',value='myCustomValue']"
```

Comment: Not a powershell cmdlet, but useful to know that appcmd.exe still exists in case the cmdlets aren't on a particular system.